# How compile C in vi and run it?

Tags: vi

Environment: MacOS, gcc, Vim7.2

I know I can do it in Emacs. Compile code and run it.
I am wondering how can I do it in vi?
I don't want to switch from vi to terminal a lot.
thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By typing `!` you can execute any shell command by the way.
You can type : to write a command and then write :

```
:!make
```

Answer (score 6):

vim does have a inbuilt **:make** command, but it has to be associated with the compiler. Some examples are:

GNU gcc compiler:

```
set makeprg=gcc\ -o\ %<\ %
```

Intel Fortran compiler:

```
set makeprg=ifort\ %\ -o\ %<
```

- \ represents blank space
- % input file
- %< output file

Answer (score 4):

Vi understands the command `make` directly, so you can just type:

```
:make
```

Comment: This is superior than SpyrosP's answer, above.

Answer (score 1):

I like to map shell commands to a leader+key. For example, (my leader key is `,` (comma), it's `\` by default I believe):

```
:map <leader>m :!make && ./program<CR>
```

Then, pressing `,m` (comma then m) executes `make && ./program` on the shell (the `<CR>` is a carriage return) Once the command has terminated, you will get a prompt to press return, and your focus will go back go vim.

Another workflow you may like is suspending vim using `<Control>+Z`, running a command on the shell, and then running `fg` to switch back to the backgrounded program.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complile by just calling `:make` you need to have a Makefile in that directory.

Comment: Isn't this rather a comment on Lawrence's answer above?

Comment: (But an important comment, I agree)